# How to downgrade mono 4.2.1 to 3.12?

Tags: 16.04, apt, system-installation, mono, c#

Mono 4.2.1 simply has way too many glitches.  I tried using the steps in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109928/rollback-mono-4-0-1-to-3-12-0), but when I type `mono --version`, I get:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Debian 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4).
```

I want mono 3.12, and I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You could try upgrading first (http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin), 4.2.1 is an old version.

Comment: Thank you, but I want 3.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135163/7312238) --- as painstaking as it was --- the only viable solution.

[My code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ruaridhw/b00e75647c8e96c2f44044c970f19c7f/raw/7fd70502e282baa03cefd075812d56c893fb3518/install-mono-3_12.sh) to run for anyone wishing to downgrade to mono V3.12 that would like to avoid navigating dependencies hell...

```
$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.1 (tarball Fri Mar  6 19:12:47 UTC 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use this code to downgrade.](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ruaridhw/b00e75647c8e96c2f44044c970f19c7f/raw/7fd70502e282baa03cefd075812d56c893fb3518/install-mono-3_12.sh) But make sure to fully remove Mono first by following [this guide](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/mono-runtime?action=remove).

Comment: It would be better to include the main steps (and a description of the code) here in your answer in case the URLs change.